# NGX Capture with Angular to Screen Shot Google Map

Tags: angular

Is it possible to use NgxCapture to take a screenshot of a google map?

I have it where it is capturing the polygons on top of the map, but not the map itself. It is just showing up as a gray box.

Is it because a google map can't be captured as a base64 PNG?

Component.ts:

```
 @ViewChild('mapCapture', { static: true }) mapCapture: any;

img = ""


capture(){
  this.captureService
    .getImage(this.mapCapture.nativeElement, true)
    .pipe(
      tap((img:any) => {
        this.img = img;
        console.log('img', img);
      })
    )
    .subscribe();
}
```

component.html

```
<div #mapCapture>
<agm-map #map id="map" [zoom]='zoom' [latitude]='latitude' [longitude]='longitude' [mapTypeId]="'hybrid'" [maxZoom]="maxZoom" [minZoom]="minZoom" (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)" [fullscreenControl]="fullscreenControl" [zoomControl]="zoomControl" [rotateControl]="true"
    [scaleControl]="scaleControl" [streetViewControl]="streetViewControl">
</agm-map>
</div>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="capture()">Capture Test</button>

<h2>My Capture:</h2>
<img src="{{img}}" />
```

And here's what it produces:

[map with polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwCXN.jpg)

[screen shot with polygons and no map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trKx0.png)